# In R how do I add every value from 1 vector to every value from a 2nd vector?

Tags: r, vector

I have two vectors in R:

```
vector1 <- c(1:24)

vector2 <- seq.int(.05,.60,.05)
```

How do I combine these vectors to a third vector in that every value in 1 is added to every value in vector 2?

Meaning the result should look like:

```
1.05, 1.10, 1.15, 1.20...
24.05,24.10,24.15,24.20...
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `outer()` here to get the sum of all the combinations. It returns a matrix so I just use `c()` to make that a vector. If you want to keep it as a matrix, just drop that part.

```
c(outer(vector2, vector1, `+`))
```